# Accessing open layer feature objects not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, openlayers

I have an array of objects holding certain keys that contain open layer feature objects as:

```
const DATA = [
    {
        FOS: new Feature({ID: 101, NAME: 'HOY',  CREATEDBY: 'ABC' }),
        FOSPART: [
                new Feature({PARTID: 11, ID: 101, NAME: 'ABC1' })
        ]
    }, 
    {
        FOS: new Feature({ID: 102, NAME: 'UHG',  CREATEDBY: 'XYZ' }),
        FOSPART: [
                new Feature({PARTID: 12, ID: 102, NAME: 'XYZ1' })
        ]
    }, 
];
```

I am passing this DATA array as prop to another component. Where I am using it as follows:

```
const {data} = props;
        this.state = {
                       data: data,
                       model: {
                                ID: null,
                                FOSPART:[]
                             }
                      }

static _createModel = (model, data) => {
        model.ID = data.FOS.get('ID');
        const Arr = model.FOSPART=[];
        if(data.FOSPART){
            for (let index = 0; index < data.FOSPART.length; index++) {
                const td = data.FOSPART[index]; 
                Arr.push(td);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have problem while inside _createModel function where:

```
 model.ID = data.FOS.get('ID'); // model.ID does not get the value and remains null
 const Arr = model.FOSPART=[];  // Arr remains empty after Arr.push, as it should place the FOSPART ol feature that is coming up with data
```

Am I doing something wrong with syntax of open layers feature object or something else?

Comment: DATA is an array.  You would need to pass DATA[0] or DATA[1]

Comment: @Mike Well yes this is how I am passing, not shown here. but in the _createModel function data is just one object from DATA array